# Поставить в центр карты google map неподвижный маркер

Tags: google-maps-api

Задача: при загрузке страницы на карте после определения геолокации (html5) появляется маркер, и после того, как он появился, при перетягивании карты он должен постоянно быть в центре. Можно лучше даже не маркер, а картинку, например, маленькую.

Главное, чтобы когда карту таскают туда-сюда, этот маркер не двигался вообще и был неподвижный, постоянно в центре карты.

Пробовал возится с функциями

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "dragend", function (event)
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "drag", function (event)
```

но когда карту тянешь, а потом отпускаешь она еще сама передвигается некоторое время, а маркер уже фиксируется и тоже съезжает... Да и при быстром таскании туда сюда (при очень скажем быстром) он тоже перескакивает чуть-чуть.
Прошу помощи.

Comment: если вам был дан правильный ответ, отметьте его галкой напротив.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div class="map-outer">
    <div class="map">тут карта гугла</div>
    <img src="image.png" class="marker">
</dic>
```

CSS:

```
.map-outer {position:relative;}
.map-outer .marker {position:absolute; top:50%; left:50%; margin:-10px 0 0 -10px;
  width:20px; height:20px; z-index:999;}
```

В margin половина высоты и ширины картинки. то есть ,если картинка будет высотой 30px и шириной 20px - тогда margin:-15px 0 0 -10px;